# Google Blocked Resources showing incorrect data

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, robots.txt

In Google Webmaster Blocked Resources tab it is showing 500+ blocked resource (like `.js` and `.css`), but when I tested those URL in *robots.txt Tester* it is showing **Allowed**, then why not Google bot is updating that tab?

Sample resource URL(s)

```
https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.7.3
https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1
https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4
https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.3
```

and this is my `robots.txt` under (https://www.example.com/robots.txt)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
//...
//...
Allow: /wp-includes/js/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
//...
//...
sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I know bot takes time to reflect real data, but issue is their form last 2-3 months and the **Last detected date: 3/23/17**, So I thought that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `Allow:` isn't a standard robots.txt directive.   Rather than use that, just remove the `Disallow: /wp-includes/` line.

Comment: thanks @StephenOstermiller for responding, I didn't knew that. I just have 2 query, `/wp-includes/` has WordPress lib files which include PHP, js, css, etc. so I don't want google to crawl PHP file and index that, and last question is when I'm testing specific assets URL in Google Webmaster  robots.txt Tester it is showing all good.

Comment: Googlebot should understand allow, but it makes it complicated.  It then uses the longest matching rule rather then using the order in the file.